# how to group elements in matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

For eg. I have `[1;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0]` this as column and I want output the group of four elements:

```
1100
1000
1110
```

How to do this? I tried it with `accumarray()` but it is not working.

Comment: Not sure what output you really want, could you put it in actual Matlab syntax into your question? Array of 3 integers or a 3x4 matrix? Or maybe something else?

Comment: Have a look at indexing methods, `reshape` and `num2str` functions. HTH

Comment: I have [1;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0] this as column and I want output the group of four elements: '1100'  '1000'  '1110' like this not as matrix as string

Comment: you want your result as string as well?

Comment: Only as string and here reshape is not working...

Comment: Do you want it as 1 string with the single ticks `' ` or do you want a 3x4 char matrix?

Comment: In column matrix the elements should be  grouped in group of 4? So it will form a string.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how is this?

```
A = [1;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0];
B = reshape(A,4,3)'; %//DONT FORGET THE `'` or your results would be wrong...
C = strcat(num2str(B)); %C is a char Array currently

C =

1  1  0  0
1  0  0  0
1  1  1  0
```

Remove the space:

you can do C(:,2:3) =[];C(:,3:4)=[];C(:,4:5)=[]; to create a 3 x 4 char Array:

```
C =

1100
1000
1110
```

but why would you right? So the better way is:

```
regexprep(cellstr(C),'[^\w'']','');  %//Now a cell Array. It is generally better practice to store strings as Cell Array instead of Char Array.

ans = 

'1100'
'1000'
'1110'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your vector only contains the elements 0 and 1 and has n*4 elements:

```
bvec = [1;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0];
bvec = char(reshape( bvec, 4, numel(bvec)/4 ) + '0').';
```

Let's break it down:

- `reshape( bvec, numel(bvec)/4, 4 );`
  breaks your column vector (could be row vector as well) into a matrix that has 4 rows (your 4 bit[?] groups), it is a 4*n matrix of type double,
- `+ '0'` adds a numerical value of 48 to represent the ASCII character '`0`'; this translates all values of `0` to `48` (ASCII '`0`') and all values of `1` to `49` (ASCII '`1`')
- `char( ... )` converts your matrix to a character type matrix.
- `.'` transposes the matrix in the very end to get a n*4 matrix.

**Result:**

```
bvec =

1100
1000
1110
```

Comment: you need to transpose the matrix after reshape, or the column/row indexes would be wrong. Or alternatively load in a row vector instead of a column vector.

Comment: @GameOfThrows, Snehal - you are right, this needs to be fixed. But I have to leave now! ;)

Comment: @Snehal: added transposition, fixed my solution. See above. ;) If you are happy with that answer please press the "accept" checkbox.